# How to maintain a table with predefined data and user data SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table containing a set of X pre-defined records which ships with my mobile app, each record with an integer auto-incrementing primary key.

Now, I want to allow users to add their own records.

However, let's say, with an app update, I want to X+10 pre-defined records with my app.

Keep in mind that the custom records primary keys are being used as foreign keys in other tables.

How do I upgrade my database, while maintaining consistency of the custom-added records foreign key ids in other tables, while keeping the new x+10 primary keys id same as shipped?

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert the additional ten rows that come with the application upgrade in a range strictly inferior to that which the client will be using, so that they won't collide and you can still assign to your new rows well-known numbers.

Unless you've initially created a "dead zone" with no inserts between the few factory-shipped initial rows and the first ID that the client will be able to assign to reserve a range for yourself, your only recourse would be to perform the ten additional inserts using negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the table with the AUTOINCREMENT keyword for the primary key, you can't reuse old keys. You'll have to add duplicates of the user added records and then update the originals with your predefined data. You'll also have to update any foreign keys in other tables that link to those records.

Why did you use AUTOINCREMENT? If you don't use it, it will still automatically increment integer keys if you don't specify a key. If you didn't use AUTOINCREMENT, you can update the primary keys (which should update the foreign keys if they are set to cascade on update) and then add the predefined records with the keys you want. You'll have to query to find out what the largest current key is and make sure the updated keys are larger than that.

Why do the key values matter? Can you design your app so that they don't? Add another column to use instead that you have more control over?